# Script to query multiple Oracle servers & instances

Tags: oracle, powershell, oracle10g

If I have a list of either database servers, or database instances, is there any way I can create and run a single script-query that would give me a list of all users in all databases? Are there any tools that would do this? Perhaps an OEM based enhancement?

Ideally I'd like to just point the script-query at a tnsnames file, with the appropriate username/password and let it run from there. We have Oracle v10.2 environment in AIX and Linux & windows.The database are not Oracle GRID managed.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, read in the list, connect to each database individually and write out the list to another file...

Comment: Yes, I can connect to oracle via powershell and execute the query but not sure about reading the list and querying each database.

Comment: Which part of "reading the list" do you need help with - getting the file content, or parsing it? Once that's done, all you need is a loop to iterate through each server. You will get much more help on SO if you show put in some effort & need help getting past an obstacle (show your code) as opposed to asking someone to write the whole thing for you.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be what you are after but you could create a set of dblinks from one db to all the others and then run a simple select statement across the dblinks

```
SELECT username from all_users@dblink1
UNION 
SELECT username from all_users@dblink2
UNION
SELECT username from all_users@dblink3
```

etc.

If you had the DBLinks in place you could even create the select dynamically